# Want to use different icon for Dynamics CRM entity depending on context

Tags: icons, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, sitemap

I have a custom entity with a N:1 relationship to Contacts and another N:1 relationship to Accounts. Basically it is a linking entity to facilitate a many to many relationship between Contact and Account, with a bit of extra information thrown in.

So now both the Account form and the Contact form have a link to a list of these joining entities in their left navigation bar, but both show the same icon.

What I would like is to show different icons on each form (ideally a Contact icon on the Account form, and an Account icon on the Contact form).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understood your question. You want alter the image of a system entity? Isn't supported, but if you want alter just the icon from site map, just upload an image of size 24x24 into the WebResources and use the relative url in the sitemap.xml file.

Comment: And that can be done on a per form basis, can it, so that the entity shows with a different icon on the sitemap for different forms?

Comment: Yes you can do it for each entity form, see here more information about [sitemap]. You have to do the procedure i gave you for each entity form (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/03/15/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-sitemap-changes.aspx).